# Azure DevOps Plugin in Intellij IDEA only show one repsitory

Tags: intellij-idea, azure-devops, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to clone a project from the Team Foundation Server, but I have only access to one repository from the server and I can't switch to another repository. I also tryed to refrech the plugin.
I'm using Intellij IDEA 2020.1.1 with Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 2016 and the plugin:[Azure DevOps](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops).
I would appreciate when I get some tips to fix this problem.

Comment: Do you mean that you can only see only one repository when trying to select a repository in the a specific TFS project? Or you want to switch repositories such as in Visual Studio Team Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Intellij IDEA with the Azure DevOps extension installed, the repositories are not shown as a tree structure . They are shown in the same level in the `Select repository`page when trying to select a repository to clone. We can filter the repositories by specifying a key word.

For example, in below screenshot I have a project called `LCgGit` and it has three git repositories (`LCGit, LCGit2, LCGit3`). So, we can filter by Project name, then select the specific repository to clone.

[image]

It will automatically open the project once we cloned the repository. And we cannot switch repositories such as in the Team Explorer in VS. We have to clone another repository again and open the project which located in that repository. We can open it in a `New Window` or `This Window`.
[image]

To switch the repositories, we can navigate to `File` -> `Open`/`Open recent` -> Select a project to open.

[image]

Besides, there's a blog which talking about [Working with IntelliJ](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/java/intellijgit/#connect-to-vsts-from-intellij) for your reference. It's still available for the Intellij IDEA 2020.1.1. But the plugin name is changed to `Azure DevOps`. So you can search `Azure DevOps` in the Marketplace.